# How can I undeploy Mobile adapters from database in the face of MFP Console error FWLSE0325: Runtime synchronisation failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-console

Deployed a few adapters and restarted Websphere (WAS) for other reasons (secure port changed, which was then reverted).

However post restart started getting MFP Console error FWLSE0325: Runtime synchronisation failed

Logs show some issues with an adapter's code.
But I'm unable to undeploy from console any more.

How do i go about undeploying the faulty adapter using the database instead?

Product Version 8.0.0.00-20210319-1338

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The erring adapter can be removed from the database. However, since this involves modifying the database records directly, exercise caution. Always take a DB backup before performing the following steps:

1. Shutdown the MobileFirst 8.0 JVM.
2. Go into the MobileFirst runtime database, look for the table "CONFIG_LINKS".
3. Here, search for the adapter that is causing the issue. You can search by the Adapter name:

   `SELECT * FROM MFPDATA.CONFIG_LINKS WHERE DISPLAY_NAME='Name_of_your_adapter_here'`;

   For instance:

   `SELECT * FROM MFPDATA.CONFIG_LINKS WHERE DISPLAY_NAME='UserLogin`';
4. You will get only a single entry. You can verify by checking the "DEPLOY_TIME" column.
5. Delete this entry from the table.
6. Save and commit the change.
7. Restart the JVM.

If you still face issues, open a ticket with MobileFirst support.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the adapter as shown in the image

[image]

Comment: Delete adapter option is not available. Only create, deploy, import.

Comment: And I can't select an adapter because of the mentioned error. It keeps loading.